# Raspbian/Raspberry Pi unexplained data usage

Tags: raspbian, linux

I have noticed that my Pis sometimes use about 100-300 mb randomly in a single day, this happen like once a month or once every two month maybe. 
any idea if Arabian does some sort of update or something like that?
I am using the pi as an IOT and have a cap on data.

also, is there a way to limit somne scripts only to use internet?

Comment: are you running raspbian full (with GUI) or lite (CLI only)? What packages have you installed above and beyond what the default install comes with? you say you use the pi as "an IOT" ... what does that even mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage pattern you describe does indeed look like unattended upgrades, check if you have them (`unattended-upgrades` package or anything with a similar name inside `/etc/apt`) and disable.

It could also be something else entirely. You should run `ntop` or `iftop` to find the process which originates the traffic, and decide what to do with it.

Comment: all I have inside /etc/apt is ```apt.conf.d   listchanges.conf  sources.list    trusted.gpg   trusted.gpg.d
auth.conf.d  preferences.d     sources.list.d  trusted.gpg```

Comment: @AdamSamus What's inside `apt.conf.d`? Any mention of unattended upgrades?

Comment: 01autoremove  01autoremove-kernels  20listchanges  50raspi  70debconf